# using Latin1 encoded characters in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I'm working on a project where our database has to be able to handle spanish characters like 'á' or 'ñ' on words being inserted or queried. Right now whenever i run an insert command like the following from cqlsh:

```
insert into test (name) values ('ñandu');
```

i get the following error:

```
ProtocolException: (ErrorMessage code=000a [Protocol error] message="Cannot decode string as UTF8: 'a4616e647527293b'; java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1")
```

Any ideas on how can I get this solved?

Comment: How do you run the query? From `cqlsh` or using a driver (java, python)?

Comment: I get it when running with cqlsh, if I do the insert via the .net driver I get the special character replaced by a '±' character

Comment: Which cassandra version are you using?

Comment: Cassandra 2.2.3, cqlsh 5.0.1 , CQL spec 3.3.1